# Question about recursive JS - from freecodecamp

Tags: javascript

There is this function:

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

How is [] being pushed first? From the code, it looks like it is being counted down from n. Can someone explain?

Bonus question: Why write like this when I can write:

```js
function countup(n){
let answer = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        (i<n) ? answer.push(i)
        : answer.push(n)
    }
return answer 
}
console.log(countup(5));
```

which is a shorter function. thank you in advance!

Comment: wait, in your bonus question, you can just push i in answer. why checking i is smaller than n?

Comment: Because  I want to count up to that number. So as long as i <= n, the loop runs. When i > n, loop stops

Comment: i meant this `(i < n) ? answer.push(i) : answer.push(n)`, not this `for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++)`. you can just write `answer.push(i)` without `(i < n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the numbers are in descending order starting from `n`, they are actually being pushed smallest number first. This is because before the `push()` operation can happen we keep going down in the recursion stack when we call `countup(n - 1)` every layer of the recursion. This is why we reach a point where `n < 1` i.e. `0` where an empty array is returned.

Next, we encounter the first `array.push()` operation and so the first number that is pushed into the array is actually 1 and not `n`. Next, the recursion layers start winding up and we push numbers 2, 3, and so on till `n`.

Yes you can achieve the same using a traditional for loop, but I guess they just want to explain how recursion works.

Comment: thank you. I kinda understand but maybe it's something we try to understand once and assume it works without question in the future

Answer (score 0):

To understand recursions, sometimes you need to follow the execution of the code manually. Now the following line causes the recursive call and subtracts one from the number and then passes it to the recursive call.

```
const countArray = countup(n - 1);
```

Now imagine, if you passed `5` to the initial function call like so:

```
countup(5);
```

As 5 is not less than 1, the `else` block will be executed. The first line in the `else` block is the recursive call. So when your program encounters the recursive call, it stops execution of the current function until that recursive function call is concluded/returned. So the first recursive call will be:

```
const countArray = countup(4);
```

consequently, the same process will be repeated until `n` equals 0. As `0` is smaller than 1, the `if` condition will evaluate to `true`. and it will return an `empty array`.

After the recursive call, it pushes the number to the array returned by recursive call. so the array at that point will contain `[0]` and then
`[0, 1]` and it will keep adding numbers till the all recursive calls have been  computed and then it will execute the rest of the intial function call.

Often times, recursion can be replaced by loops but thats not the case always. As a programmer one should be aware of this important topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since `countup()` is fully divided by an if statement that depends on `n`, let's first see what exectutes for different vales of `n`.

To make it a lot easier to follow, we'll append our current `n` to  `countArray`'s variable name:

```
n == 5:
   const countArray5 = countup(4);
   countArray5.push(5);
   return countArray5;
⋮
n == 1: 
   const countArray1 = countup(0);
   countArray1.push(1);
   return countArray1;
n == 0: 
   return [];
```

Now let's sequentially expand each inner call to `countup(n)`:

```
countup(5) {
   const countArray5 = countup(4);
   countArray5.push(5);
   return countArray5;
}
```

```
countup(5) {
  const countArray5 = countup(4) {
     const countArray4 = countup(3);
     countArray4.push(4);
     return countArray4;  
   };
  countArray5.push(5);
  return countArray5;
}
```

Expanding until `countup(0)`:

```
countup(5) {
  const countArray5 = countup(4) {
    const countArray4 = countup(3) {
      const countArray3 = countup(2) {
        const countArray2 = countup(1) {
          const countArray1 = countup(0) // countup(0) returns [] so countArray1 = [];
          countArray1.push(1); // Then push '1' to countArray1;
          return countArray1;  // Return [1] at counterArray2 = countup(1) above
        };
        countArray2.push(2); // countArray2 was [1], now push '2' to make it [1,2]
        return countArray2; // Return [1,2] at countArray3 = countup(2) above 
      };
      countArray3.push(3); // Push '3' to countArray3 => [1,2,3]
      return countArray3;  // return [1,2,3] at countArray4 = countup(3)
    };
    countArray4.push(4);  // Push '4' to countArray4 => [1,2,3,4]
    return countArray4;   // Return [1,2,3,4] at countArray5 = countup(4)
  };
  countArray5.push(5); // Push '5' to countArray5 => [1,2,3,4,5]
  return countArray5;  // countup(5) returns [1,2,3,4,5] 
}
```